# how to stream results of a restful query (ajax-style) in python

Tags: python, ajax, rest, flask, routes

I am working on a Restful app.  One of the methods takes a little while to return and I wanted to stream back status until it completes.  Please bear with me as I am not a web developer :-)... Here is what I have:

```
# this is what I normally use to generate the status.  It works great for
# those cases where the status changes immediately:
def door_status():
    global door
    status = {"door count": door.position }
    return Response(json.dumps(status),  mimetype='application/json')

def generate(door_thread, state):
    while door_thread.current_state == state:
        yield ','.join("good stuff goes here") + '\n'

# This is the endpoint that I am having issues with.  door.close_door()
# returns immediately, but the door takes a while to close.  I'd like to
# continue returning status until the door is completely closed.
@app.route(ROOT + 'close_door', methods=['POST'])
def close_door():
global door
    # the following method returns immediately but it takes a while 
    # for the door to close:
    door.close_door() 
    # until the door is finally closed, return status:
    return Response(generate(door, State.opening), mimetype='application/json')

    # Note that the following return works but it does not show the updated
    # status of the door actually being closed:
    # return door_status(), 201
```

In a related application, I use the following code to get the results of the REST call and display them:

```
try:
    rtn = urllib2.urlopen(req, context=ctx)
    data = json.load(rtn)
    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter()
    pp.format = my_safe_repr
    print "Success:" + str(rtn.code)
    pp.pprint(data)
except urllib2.HTTPError as err:
    print str(err) + ":"
    print err.read()
```

Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Comment: This is a little tricky since theoretically you don't have valid JSON until you've received the *entire* response. Have you considered using pagination?

Comment: Suever, Please elaborate...  I'm not necessarily stuck on json...